# Proving a formula for the number of square-free integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, mobius-function

$S(n)$ denotes the number of square-free integers not exceeding $n$. I am interested in proving
$$S(n)=\sum\limits_{j=1}\limits^{n}\sum\limits_{d^2|j}\mu(d)$$
I have so far been able to prove
$$S(n)=\sum\limits_{j=1}\limits^{n}|\mu(j)|$$
and it is known that
 $\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)=1$ if $n=1$
and  $\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)=0$ if $n>1$
however, I am having difficulty moving forward specifically because of the double summation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to prove that $|\mu(j)|=\sum_{d^2\mid j}\mu(d)$. If $j$ is a squarefree number, both the LHS and the RHS equal one, obviously. Let us assume $j=MN$ with $\gcd(M,N)=1$, $M>1$ and $N$ being squarefree. The RHS just depends on $\sum_{\substack{d\mid M\\ d\text{ squarefree}}}\mu(d) $, which equals zero. And so does the LHS.

Comment: Yes, that was my inclination--I'm having a harder time formalizing that in a proof, again because of the double summation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, how are you sure $\sum_{d^2\mid j}\mu(d)=1$ if j is a square-free number? As I understand it the summation doesn't even 'work' since j isn't divisible by any $d^2$

Comment: @GwenDi: I have not stated that $\sum_{d^2\mid j}(\ldots)$ equals one, I have stated that such sum equals zero. If it is a sum over an empty set, it equals zero by convention.

Comment: I think you have, no? *"If j is a squarefree number, both the LHS and the RHS equal one, obviously."*

Comment: @GwenDi: if $j$ is a squarefree number then $\mu(j)$ equals $\pm 1$. If $j$ is a squarefree number it has a unique square divisor, which is $1$, and $\mu(1)=1$.